# Как правильно оформить вопросы внутри предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, кавычки, вопрос

*Для заключения успешной сделки он должен был ответить для себя на вопросы — «надежна ли компания, с которой заключается договор», «какую пользу он извлечет от этого сотрудничества» и т. д.*

Вопрос ставить в кавычках? Ставить ли тире перед вопросами?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, если человек отвечает на вопросы "для себя", то это означает, что эти вопросы он формулирует и ставит перед собой сам — то есть это не чужие, не цитируемые слова.
Прямая речь при цитировании выглядела бы так: "Какую пользу ты извлечешь от этого сотрудничества?" Поэтому, думаю, кавычки не нужны.
Вместо тире необходимо двоеточие ([см.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150)).

Тогда предлагаю две версии пунктуации.
**1.** С сочетанием "и т. д.", которое, по моему мнению, нивелирует вопросительную интонацию:
*Для заключения успешной сделки он должен был ответить для себя на вопросы: надежна ли компания, с которой заключается договор, какую пользу он извлечет от этого сотрудничества и т. д.*

> Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложносочиненного предложения, если все образующие его части или только последняя из них заключает в себе вопрос...

**2.** Без "и т. д." можно поставить вопросительный знак после каждого вопроса ("Перед прямым вопросом, включенным в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения, ставится двоеточие"):
*Для заключения успешной сделки он должен был ответить для себя на вопросы: надежна ли компания, с которой заключается договор? какую пользу он извлечет от этого сотрудничества?*

> При смысловом подчеркивании отдельных членов вопросительного... предложения знаки препинания ставятся после каждого из членов...
> Однако прописные буквы заменяются строчными, если перед перечислением стоят знаки двоеточие или тире (впереди имеется обобщение): ...*Она спросила, кто он, не француз ли, и стала по его просьбе гадать: **бельгиец? датчанин? голландец?*** (Наб.)...

[§76. Вопросительный знак](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/41.htm)
[Знаки конца предложения внутри предложения](http://www.telenir.net/jazykoznanie/pravila_russkoi_orfografii_i_punktuacii_polnyi_akademicheskii_spravochnik/p3.php#metkadoc6) (§ 5)

Comment: *то есть это не чужие, не цитируемые слова* — но всё равно формулировка вопроса, а не компонент предложения, родовое слово же есть, в отличие от примера из правила.

Comment: Э... Простите, какое родовое слово?

Comment: "Вопросы". Двоеточие же не отменяет кавычки, без него они явно нужны.

Comment: Такие вопросы — это как бы предложения в предложении, из-за этого нужны кавычки. У Розенталя кавычки ставятся в таких случаях, один из примеров: *На вопрос мой: «Жив ли старый смотритель?» — никто не мог дать мне удовлетворительного ответа.*

Answer (score 1):

Перечисление требует двоеточия, а между перечисляемыми (в общем случае) ставится запятая. В этой же фразе, где есть внутреннее обособление запятыми, следует ставить точку с запятой: «...на вопросы: надежна ли компания, с которой заключается договор; какую пользу он извлечет от этого сотрудничества и т. д.».